# Is there an easy way to find particular text built from RichText in a Flutter test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

For example, I may have one **`RichText`** in current widget tree, that looks like

```dart
RichText(
 text: TextSpan(
   text: 'Hello ',
   style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
   children: <TextSpan>[
     TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
     TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
   ],
 ),
)
```

I try to use `find.text('Hello bold world!')` but it doesn't work because it's not a Text.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simplest solution is to put a key on the RichText and read it that way.

If that's not a good fit for whatever reason, you can use find.byWidgetPredicate and pass a function that matches RichText widgets whose text.toPlainText() returns the string you want.

Comment: Thanks, the second solution will be like:`expect(find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget widget) => widget is RichText && widget.text.toPlainText() == 'Hello bold world'), findsOneWidget);`

Comment: In my case, widget.text.toPlainText() actually contained 0-width space characters at the end (probably because of empty spans). The only way I got it to work was to use .startsWith : `(widget) => widget is RichText && widget.text.toPlainText().startsWith('hello')`

Answer (score 35):

### Framework solution

I have recently [contributed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/87197) this feature to the Flutter framework, i.e. to the built-in finders.

#### `find.text()`

You can now enable a [`findRichText` parameter](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/flutter/blob/d78390df3742b7d84f56d533075f4b76fc4b6890/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/finders.dart#L58), which will then also find standalone `RichText` widgets:

```dart
find.text(
  'Hello bold world!',
  findRichText: true,
)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot for your contribution, this'll be great in stable!

Comment: This a great contribution. Can confirm this is on the stable channel in Flutter v2.10.1.

Comment: Nice! Can you also do `find.textContaining()`? :)

Comment: Cool, saved myself from scratching my head

Answer (score 14):

Here's the find.byWidgetPredicate call.

```
find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => fromRichTextToPlainText(widget) == 'Hello bold world!')
```

Here's the fromRichTextToPlainText helper function. Pass it the RichText widget, it will return the plain text.

```
String fromRichTextToPlainText(final Widget widget) {
  if (widget is RichText) {
    if (widget.text is TextSpan) {
      final buffer = StringBuffer();
      (widget.text as TextSpan).computeToPlainText(buffer);
      return buffer.toString();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved for this by digging into the widget a bit more manually

```
    final richTextWidget = tester.element(richTextFinder).widget as RichText;
    print(richTextWidget.text.children);
```

With the children, I can assert they are generated as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by enabling `findRichText: true` like this,

```
expect(find.text("${input.newItem.price.toPrice}/${weight!.unit}", findRichText: true), findsOneWidget);
```