# Flutter: How to get properly RichText data when testing?

Tags: flutter, testing, integration-testing, deprecated, flutter-test

I'm currently writing a **test** in order to verify if a value **inside** a **RichText** is valid or not.

Here is the widget I need to test:

```dart
RichText(
  key: ValueKey('RichTextKey'),
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Part 1 - ',
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Part 2'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

So currently I found a way to do it but it seems to be **deprecated** :/

Here is how I test for now (*deprecated*):

```dart
final richText0Finder = find.byKey(
  ValueKey('RichTextKey'),
);

final richText0Widget = tester.element(richText0Finder).widget as RichText;

// second ".text" is deprecated here :/
expect(richText0Widget.text.text, 'Part 1 - ');

// no problem with TextSpan inside RichText, the first element is not the one inside RichText...
final textSpan0 = richText0Widget.text.children.last as TextSpan;
expect(textSpan0.text, 'Part 2');
```

Deprecated say:

```
'text' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. InlineSpan does not innately have text. Use TextSpan.text instead. This feature was deprecated after v1.7.3..
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
```

But I don't know how to get `InlineSpan` data inside a **RichText** widget ?

Any help would be great :) ,
Thanks !

Comment: Use `find.text('...', findRichText: true);` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68946630/5301229.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution, just need to wrap `richText0Widget.text` as a `TextSpan` widget :

```dart
expect((richText0Widget.text as TextSpan).text, 'Part 1 - ');
```

Hope it can well :)